# Can someone explain an S-Statistic analysis?

Tags: statistics

What exactly is an S-Statistic analysis, and what does this equation represent?

$(D-F)^2/σ^2$

I understand that σ is the uncertainty of D, but that's about it.

Comment: What is your source for this expression? It's likely to define more than just $\sigma$.

Comment: I agree w jg. I know (knew?) something about this field but don’t remember what F and D are. A link about that equation and i can probably remember and then explain it ?

Comment: This question ought to be asked on a mathematics forum, maybe *Cross Validated SE*. It has no obvious connection with physics.